# EventGrid retry using mock message?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventgrid, retry-logic

Is there a clean retry mechanism for EventGrid messages that were successfully delivered, but downstream processes failed and message needs to be sent again?

**Example:**

- EventGrid message triggered based on blob upload to Azure Storage
- EventGrid message in turn, triggers an Azure Function
- Function receives message
- Function fails somewhere downstream

Is there a clean way to **resend the EventGrid message** rather than re-uploading the blob to storage to generate a new message?

Looking for a way to maybe craft and send retry messages for a bunch of blobs?

Something like (pseudocode):

```
ForEach blob in GET_BLOBS
  - where Modified Timestamp > Today - 1,
  - generate EventGrid message
    {
        "blobUrl":"https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/dir/file.json",
    }
  - send EventGrid message to Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I do recommend to read the document [Event Grid message delivery and retry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry).

In the case, when your subscriber invokes a downstream process in the **async** manner using a *PUSH_ACK* pattern, the AEG supports also delivering an event message in the *PULL* pattern, where the delivery target resource is used for saving the event message for its latter pull up based on the needs, for instance: storage queue, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I read the doc. It addresses only scenarios where message is *not* ACK'd. The PULL pattern you mentioned sounds like the way to go to protect against "lost" messages moving forward. I will research how to implement queue trigger for the Function.